# PHP select from tbl / fetch array issue

Tags: php

Im having an issue with fetch_array. I keep getting the return of record not found. With every thing that I have looked at it seems to me that this code should work. Sorry im new to php web development.

```
$JobNumber = NULL;
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")
{
$JobID = $_POST['jobid'];
include('pmconnect.php');
$sql="SELECT * FROM tblJobMaster WHERE JobNumber=" . $JobID;
$result=$conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows==0)
    {
    echo "Record not found.<br>";
    die(0);
    }
$row=$result->fetch_array();

echo '<table style="text-align: left; width: 100%;" border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">';
echo "<tbody>";
echo "<tr>";
echo '<td style="vertical-align: top; text-align: right;">Job Number:<br>';
echo "</td>";
echo '<td style="vertical-align: top;">' .$row[0] . '<br>';
echo "</td>";
echo '<td style="vertical-align: top; text-align: right;">Engineer:<br>';
echo '</td>';
echo '<td style="vertical-align: top;">' . $row[3] .'<br>';
echo '</td>';
echo "</tr>";
echo "<form action=pmAssignEngineer2.php method=post id=usrform>";
echo "<input type=hidden name=JobID value=" . $JobID . ">";
echo "<input type=submit value=\"Update\" name=lookup>";
echo "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</form>";
echo "</tbody>";

}

else
{
echo "<form action=pmAssignEngineer.php method=post>";
echo "<table border=2>";
    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>Job Number:</td>";
        echo "<td><input type=text name=JobID></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
echo "<input type=submit value=\"Lookup\" name=lookupQ><br>";
echo "</form>"; 
}
```

Comment: `name=JobID` is not equal to `$_POST['jobid']` it must be `$_POST['JobID']`

Comment: Your field name is `JobID`, but your key in `$_POST` is `jobid`.

Comment: @RuchishParikh The mysql extension is deprecated in PHP5 and discontinued in PHP7. Please use mysqli or PDO and do not recommend using the mysql extension. Thanks.

Comment: You should really consider putting quotes arround the html tags' parameters' values like <input type="hidden" name="JobID" .... />. Haven't tried if that works without but anyway.. Then use $_POST['JobID'] ( respect case ! ) and finally, where do you initialize $JobID for the first time, when nothing has been posted already ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML elements are posted to `$_POST` if form method is `post`.

The element name is key and value is array value.

And the keys are case-sensitive.

In your case, your element has name `JobID` and you are referring `jobid`.

Obviously, the keys of `$_POST` do not match as `jobid` and `JobID` are different.

```
<input type=text name=JobID>
```

So, update the following line:

```
$JobID = $_POST['jobid'];
```

To

```
$JobID = $_POST['JobID'];
```